# Как правильно сокращать название города Санкт-Петербурга?

Tags: орфография, дефис, слитно-дефис

Можно ли сокращать название города Санкт-Петербурга до С.Петербург? На грамоте.ру отвечают, что так сокращать можно, но после точки нужно добавить дефис (С.-Петербург). На царских картах я неоднократно видел написание С.Петербургъ (дефиса нет). Может, на наличие дефиса повлияла советская реформа правописания, или же оба варианта верны и по сей день? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

А для чего нужно сокращение? В списках литературы сокращают как в издательских данных: Санкт-Петербург — СПб., Москва — М., другие города (которые тоже случаются) пишутся полностью. А в одной рассылке автореферата я встретил такое: «Ведущая организация: ОКБ "Электроавтоматика", г. С.-Петербург». (Но это написание было неуверенно осуждено: сказали, что «кажется, так нельзя».) «Справочник издателя и автора» (М., 1999) настаивает на СПб., с пометой: «по ГОСТ 7.12-93». В крайнем случае пишите полностью: «Санкт-Петербург». «С.-Петербург» мне тоже не нравится: тогда уж и «С.-Франциско», что ли? А вариант царского времени в наши дни точно не указ.